Identify a 2 player matching card game with 4 cards
Help me find this card game I used to play with my dad.
I have gone through hundreds of websites and posts but can't find an answer, so my last step is to ask you great people.
I am assuming this is a rare variant, or a geographically local game (South Asian).
Game rules
Players: 2.
To win: Have 4 matching cards of the same value e.g. four Jacks, or four 10s.
Deck: Single standard deck of 52 cards.
Setup:

Both players are dealt 4 cards each.
(hidden to the opponent, but visible at all times to the card holder)
One card is placed face up as the discard pile.
The rest of the deck is placed face down as the draw pile.

Gameplay:

On each players turn, they can choose to take one of two actions:

Pick up the top card from the draw
pile (face down)
Pick up the top card from the discard pile (face up)


At the end of turn the player must discard down to 4 cards.
Players keep taking turns until they have 4 of a kind.
E.g. x4 Jacks or x4 10s.

Note: If the draw pile (face down) has run out, then the all cards in the discard pile (except the most recent one at the top) are re-shuffled and placed face down to become the new draw pile.
It is a really fun game as you can purposely try to throw the opponent off by picking up a card they discarded (to make them think that it is the set you are going after, etc.)
I want to play this game with other people, but I have no idea what its called. I would be thrilled to find an answer, and if you haven't come across this game I hope you enjoy it.

I think you might have missed a rule? If the opponent picks a card from your hand, you will only have 3 cards left in your hand, do you pick 2 cards, or don’t you discard a card, or do you play with only 3 cards the next round?

Hi @Snostorp, you are correct, to clarify there is no picking cards from each others hands, you can only get a card from the opposing players hand if they drop the card to pick up one from the top of the deck or from the top of the discard pile.

This is a draw-and-discard game, also known as Rummy.  So we are looking for a 4-cards-hand Rummy where the goal is a Set of 4.  Check the Oriental Rummy Games at https://www.pagat.com/rummy/
